# Hardware and Sotfware saves during Context Switch in xv6

Tags: unix, operating-system, kernel, context-switch, xv6

I'm studying the xv6 *context switch* on [Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces](http://ostep.org) book. I can not fully understand the **Saving and Restoring Context** section of [Chapter 6](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/cpu-mechanisms.pdf) (page 8).

- Why there are two types of register saves/restore that happen during the Context Switch protocol?
- What is the difference between the mentioned *user registers* and *kernel registers*?
- What is the meaning of:

  > By switching stacks, the kernel enters the call to the switch code in the context of one process (the one that was interrupted) and returns in the context of another (the soon-to-be-executing one).

Answer (score 1):

> Why there are two types of register saves/restore that happen during the Context Switch protocol?

Assuming you are talking about p. 10. The text is a bit misleading (but not as nearly bad as I have seen in some books). They are comparing register save in interrupts those to context switches. It's really not a good comparison.

Register saves in interrupt handling is done the same way as you do it in a function call (and not like it is done in a context switch). You have to preserve any register values you are going to muck with at the start interrupt handling then restore them before the interrupt handler return. You are only dealing with general purpose registers as well (ie not process control registers).

Register save in context switches are done en-masse. All the process's registers get saved at once. An interrupt service routine might save 4 registers while a context switch might save more than 30.

> What is the difference between the mentioned user registers and kernel registers?

Some registers are accessible and modifiable in user mode. The general purpose registers would certainly be user registers. The processor status is a mixed bag because it can be read in user mode, it can be modified in some ways in user mode by executing instructions but it is generally read only in user mode. You might call that a user register or might not.

There are other registers that are only accessible in kernel mode. For example, there will be registers that define the process's page table. Other registers will define the system dispatch table.

Note here the only some of the kernel mode registers are process registers (e.g. those setting up page tables) and need to be saved and restored with the process. Other kernel registers are system wide (e.g. those for timers and the system dispatch table). Those do not change with the process.

> By switching stacks, the kernel enters the call to the switch code in the context of one process (the one that was interrupted) and returns in the context of another (the soon-to-be-executing one).

This is a little bit misleading in the excerpt but might make more sense if I read the book carefully.

A process context switch requires changing all the per-process registers to a block whose structure is defined by the CPU. What I find misleading in your excerpt is that the context switch involves more than just switching stacks.

Typically a context change looks something like:

```
SAVE_PROCESS_CONTEXT_INSTRUCTION address_of_the_current_process_context_block
LOAD_PROCESS_CONTEXT_INSTRUCTION address_of_the_next_process_context_block
```

As soon as you load a process context you are in the new process. That switch includes changing the kernel mode stack.

Some operating systems use terminology in their documentation that implies interrupts (especially) and (sometimes) exceptions being handlers are not done in the context of a process. In fact, the CPU ALWAYS executes in the context of a process.

As soon as you execute the context switch instruction you are in the new process BUT in an exception or interrupt handler in kernel mode. The change in the kernel stack causes the return from the exception or interrupt to resume the new process's user mode code.

So you are already in the context of the process with the PCB switch.The resulting change in the kernel mode stack pointer (ie establishing a new kernel mode stack) causes return from the exception or interrupt to pick up where the new process was before it entered kernel mode (via exception or interrupt)

Comment: It might be better to say that initial execution of hardware interrupts take place in an unknown process context, (well, unless there is only one process running:).